# Ошибка MissingComponentException

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я решил попробовать новую версию Unity и написал код который работает в прошлой.
Теперь мне выдаёт ошибку:
MissingComponentException: There is no 'CharacterController' attached to the "Player" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a CharacterController to the game object "Player". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
UnityEngine.CharacterController.Move (UnityEngine.Vector3 motion) (at :0)

Код:

```
public float _speed = 0.6f;
private CharacterController _characterController;

private void Start()
{
    _characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if(_characterController == null)
        Debug.Log("CharacterController is NULL");
}

private void Update ()
{
    float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * _speed;
    float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * _speed;
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ);
    movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, _speed);

    movement *= Time.deltaTime;
    movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
    _characterController.Move(movement);
    
}
```

P.S. методом тыка я выяснил, что дело в самой последней строчке, но при любом её изменении скрипт отказывается работать.

Comment: Вам ведь прямым текстом пишут, что не так и как исправить. `There is no 'CharacterController' attached to the "Player" game object, but a script is trying to access it.` - Дословно "К игровому объекту "Player" не прикреплен "CharacterController", но скрипт пытается получить к нему доступ.". То есть, вы в испекторе не прицепили нужный скрипт.

Comment: А как его прицепить?

Comment: Наверно перенести в нужное поле инспектора?

Answer (score 0):

Иду на помощь!

в строке `private CharacterController _characterController;` вы создали поле

в строке `_characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();` вы выдали полю значение

в проверки ниже Вы уверены что не получали данный Лог?

```
if(_characterController == null)
    Debug.Log("CharacterController is NULL");
```

Советую использовать явные **"контракты"**, гарантию того что компонент будет присутствовать а не делать проверку на его наличие, я предполгаю что данный компонент отсутствует на обьекте и у вас выходит данное сообщение в консоле **CharacterController is NULL**

Создание **"контракта"** происходит путём добавления атрибута `[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]` в обьекте где он необходим

**Пример из документации Unity:**

```
using UnityEngine;

// PlayerScript requires the GameObject to have a Rigidbody component
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

[Ссылка на документацию от Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html)